# How to remove digits in a string except those in hashtags using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm processing some twitter texts, and I want to remove all numbers in a tweet except those that appear in hashtags. For example,

```
'I wrote 16 scripts in #code100day challenge2019 in 10day'
```

should become

```
'I wrote scripts in #code100day challenge in day'
```

Note that numbers not separated from alphabetic characters should also be removed (i.e. `'challenge2019'` --> `'challenge'`, `'10day'` --> `'day'`).

I tried:

```
text = 'I wrote 16 scripts in #code100day challenge2019 in 10day'
text = re.sub(r"^(?!#)\d+", "", text)
```

But it does not do anything to the input string.

I also did negative lookbehind, trying to remove all digits except those following the `'#'` symbol:

```
text = re.sub(r"(?<!#)\d+", "", text)
```

But now it removes all the numeric characters no matter in hashtag or not:

```
'I wrote  scripts in #codeday challenge in day'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to match `#` followed by non-space characters (and, if matched, replace with the whole match, effectively leaving the hashtag alone), *or* match digit characters and remove them:

```
output = re.sub(
    r'#\S+|\d+',
    lambda match: match.group(0) if match.group(0).startswith('#') else '',
    txt
)
```

If you can use the regex module, you can use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` after matching hashtags instead, to effectively skip them if matched:

```
output = regex.sub(r'#\S+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\d+', '', txt)
```

Comment: Thank you! Both work perfectly, while using regex is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that using an alternation would likely be faster and simpler than lookarounds:

```
import re

test_str = "10 I wrote 16 scripts in #code100day challenge2019 in 10day 100 "

print(re.sub(r"^\s+|\s+$","",re.sub(r"\s{2,}"," ",re.sub(r"(#\S+)|(\d+)", "\\1", test_str))))
```

#### Output

```
I wrote scripts in #code100day challenge in day
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xdXJ7O/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/xdXJ7O/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: Thanks! The expression works, while using regex module can be faster

Comment: Do you think this is possible using look-behind and such? This `text2 = re.sub("(?<!#\D+)\d+", "", text)` doesn't work for example.

Comment: @Emma thanks for the answer! If a regex pro says its complicated then I think I should just stop thinking about it lol.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

Just checking for the digit with space(Before/after) and replacing with space.

```
text = 'I wrote 16 scripts in #code100day challenge2019 in 10day'
re.sub("\d+ | \d+", " ", text)
```

O/P: 'I wrote  scripts in #code100day challenge in day'

You can use like this also, which will give the same result

```
re.sub("\d+\s|\s\d+", " ", text)
```

Comment: Won't work if the hashtag ends in a number, e.g #code100

Comment: Also won't work if the digit to be removed occurs in the middle of a word, without spaces on either side, eg `a11a`